# How do I deal with too many cooks spoiling the broth?

Tags: management

I work for a corporation that owns multiple companies.

At the highest level is the owner of the corporation, under him are two CEOs, under them is a general manager, managers for each department (HR, IT etc) and then finally the managers of each of the companies.

I am the sole web designer and developer for the corporation and all of the companies.

All of these higher ups have different ideas for what should be done and none of them are willing to budge (to the point where I can't even arrange meetings because two of them insist we have them at their specific locations and neither of them is willing to travel or do it online)

When I work with 1 person at a time, things go smoothly. Unfortunately, the projects need to be signed off by all of the previously mentioned higher ups before the projects go live. War breaks out every time this happens as each person tries to get their plans ideas and agendas pushed forward while stopping the others (It really feels like a not so fun game of Netrunner...)

This caused 4 months worth of work to be pushed live today only to be taken down an hour later (the majority of the time was spent with the higher ups arguing over what should be done, then they all quietened down and I got to work with what I was told was going ahead only to have them argue it out again when we were ready to go live)

How am I supposed to handle this in a way that does not involve leaving my job?

Comment: What are your goals with "handle this?" Get them on the same page? Keep your job? Enjoy your job? Find ways to avoid having to deal with them? Get additional developers hired? Have only one actual manager? You don't really say what you are hoping to accomplish here, which makes this harder to really answer

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple options.

1.) **Leave** I don't see a bright future for this company.  No company can continue to be successful with this type of leadership.  The owner or the CEOs need to step in and put their foot down.  If the CEOs are the problem and the owner will not step in then it's like the company is on a plane and the engines failed...you are just going to glide but eventually you are going to nose dive and crash.

2.) You step up. Give them some options.  Say "this is what we can do and since we can't come to a decision I think we should vote on it and go with the majority."

The fact that some of them won't do the meeting online is just absurd.  But to fix this maybe have the owner of CEO choose the place to meet.  Or if they can't get the kahunas to do it then you choose and it looks like you can please all but two people.  If you just say "this is where we are having it because it works the best and we will be making a decision at this meeting" I'm sure they can find time to show up, either in person or online, because they will probably want to be apart of the decision.

Somehow you need to find a neutral ground/location/environment for these people.

If you have a good owner and CEOs then eventually these "bad cooks" should be put in their place but if you have a bunch of people who can't put their egos aside for the betterment of the company I don't see this ever getting better and I would consider a new place of employment.

Comment: I am amazed that there would only be one web person/developer for a group of corporations.  Either that, or there must be some title inflation going on with the owned organizations...;)  I can't believe that all of them were involved in hiring you.  I would ask the top person who hired you to help out in establishing the decision meeting locations/times.  The fact that people are not willing to meet online or via phone call seems childish and short sighted.

Comment: "leave" should be the very last option.  Just consider what you will answer at your next interview when asked "And what did you do before quitting?"

Answer (score 1):

Consider just asking everybody else who may decide what you should do, when a change request comes in, and await consensus.

The "Please everyone agree" pushes the disagreement up front instead of having it linger to the last moment, and the email trail will most likely clearly show that you need a direct superior and only one.

Comment: Agreed. You should have exactly one person telling you what to work on, and who you should be able to go to with questions. That person should likewise shield you from external interference, and they can have all those arguments  about the proper direction without having to involve you.

Answer (score 1):

There is not doubt this is a bad situation with lots of politics and territorial urinations going on, but how does it reflect directly on you? Are you being held responsible for failed projects and having your bonus and/or promotions denied? Does this cause you to put in extra-hours?

Again, I get it is frustrating. We all want to be efficient and have meaningful work, but these types of huge battles at the top are probably out of your reach.

**Single Sign-Off** Does there really have to be a sign-off on everything by all three? That's the real problem. Are some companies more responsible for their part of the website? Why not just get sign-off from one of them (Hopefully the one who is most cooperative and available.)? Focus on satisfying your direct supervisor or which one can fire you.

**Stop trying to hold a meeting.** People go crazy in congregations anyway. Just let them know where the site/documents are where they can review and they have until date 'X' to indicate their disapproval. Otherwise, you'll assume their silence is a form of acceptance.